# Find the Spectral representation of the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

How to Find the Spectral representation of the matrix A

\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 2 \\
-2 & 2\end{bmatrix}

How can I Illustrate that $Ax=b$ can be solved geometrically using the appropriately chosen coordinate system on a piece of graph paper.

Comment: find $A$ 's eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: @janmarqz I just need to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors ? what after that

Comment: well, study the example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Two_dimensional_example

Comment: I got that but How will I answer ---  How can I Illustrate that Ax=b can be solved geometrically using the appropriately chosen coordinate system on a piece of graph paper ??

Comment: Ok, if $Q$ is a diagonalizing matrix for $A$ try: $(Q^{-1}AQ)Q^{-1}x=Q^{-1}b$, this has the effect of writing your original equation in a simpler form

Comment: check this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B7%2C2%7D%2C%7B-2%2C2%7D%7D&lk=4&num=1